# copy the data of a file multiple times into another file

Tags: shell-script, shell

Here I want to write some shell code and my question is, I want to copy one data file multiple times into another new file.
For example:
*File1* contains 3000 lines of data. Now I want this data multiple times in another single file (*File1 * 3 > File2*). Here I am copying *File1*'s data *3* times and saving it to *File2*.  Now *File2* contains *12000* lines of data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you prefer loops:

```
for i in {1..3}; do cat file1 >> file2; done
```

**[edit]**

> how to give dynamically n value in for loop on shell script

put this into `myCopyScript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1.. $3 }; do cat $1 >> $2; done
```

make the it executable

```
chmod u+x myCopyScript.sh
```

then call it like this:

```
myCopyScript.sh file1 file2 4711
```

Comment: Though of course this command is slightly different to Konstantin's answer, in that if file2 already exists its existing contents will be retained and file1 appended three times after its existing contents.

Comment: @Muzer sure, but I guess this is acceptable... ;o)

Comment: Indeed, I was just mentioning it!

Comment: @Muzer can u help me on this question:
how to give dynamically n value in for loop on shell script...
for((i=1;i<n;i++))..
I will give n value as a input!!Hope u got my point

Comment: Where's the input coming from? You can just do something like i<"$var" where $var is your variable (eg "$1" for the first command-line input). And as Timothy says, you should mark an answer as accepted by clicking the tick.

Comment: @Muzer i want to give the input from console..
For example:
`echo "enter n:"`
`read n`
`for((i=1;i<n;i++)); do`
`cat x >> y ;`
`done`

Answer (score 7):

Simple solution

```
cat File1 File1 File1 > File2
```

Comment: It's just solution for small `i`. If you want more, use @TimothyTruckle answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #!/bin/sh
echo "Enter data file name or exact path:"
read f
echo "Enter new file name:"
read nf
echo "Enter how many times you want to copy:"
read n
for (( i=1 ; i<=$n; i++)); do
cat $f >> $nf ;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the very same task and the answer by @timothy-truckle has helped a lot.

In order to extend it a bit, I put here my script's code:

```
if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
    echo "bash cat_files.sh vocab203nb/vsekz.lm 10 vocab203nbx/vsekz.lm"
    exit 0
fi
fname=$1
times=$2
new_fname=$3
echo "file: $fname"
echo "will be concatenated $times times"
echo "and saved as $new_fname"



for i in $(seq 1 $times); do
    cat $fname >> $new_fname;
done
```

You can then run the script in the terminal providing the necessary arguments:

```
bash cat_files.sh src/tmp.lm 4 dst/tmp.lm
```

where:

*src/tmp.lm* is a file that should be copied multiple times

*4* - is an integer number declaring how many times a file should be concatenated

*dst/tmp.lm* is a file that should store the result

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In `tcsh`:

```
repeat 3 cat file1 > file2
```

`zsh` also has a `repeat` command (a keyword in the language there), but there that needs to be:

```
{repeat 3 cat file1} > file2
```

As without the braces, the redirection is taken as part of the command that is repeated.